# How do I determine if a pipe is frozen?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, freezing

I have a shower which has no hot or cold water this cold (2F outside) morning.

I can get to some of the piping directly behind it, inside an attic.  There is at least 8-10 inches of insulation between the pipes and the attic.

I <s>lost</s> temporarily don't have access to my non-contact thermometer, so I can't tell if these pipes are actually cold enough to be frozen.

Without a thermometer, and without obvious splitting/leaking, how can you determine whether a pipe you have access to is actually frozen or not in the sections you have access to?

Comment: I've got an indoor safe propane heater running, the bathroom itself is 98F now and has been for a few hours.  This is probably not the first time this has happened, there is lots of evidence in the attic that insulation has been placed, removed, placed, removed in that spot.

Comment: lick the pipes, if your tongue sticks then the pipe is frozen